# How do I leave a fixed value in a mask with regex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have a time mask, it accepts +1000h, but I wanted to set:00 after the hours

```
    return varTemp
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/(\d{2,4})(\d{2}$)/, "$1:$2")
  };
```

In this mask, : stays between hours and minutes.
But I wanted to leave :00 fixed, without the minutes.

---

```
const maskHours = (value) => {
  return (
    value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/(\d{2})/, "$1:00")
  );
};
```

In this mask, the value :00 is fixed, but the result is not good.

Thanks to whoever helps me!

Comment: Perhaps you only want to add the `:00` to the end only? Like `.replace(/\d{2}$/, "$&:00")`

Comment: That!
But when I add it like this, the result up to the first 2 is, for example: 22:00
But if I add one more number, it would be: 22002:00
The mask adds 00
And this mask, it's hourly load... I need it for more than 100-1000 hours :/

Comment: You probably want `.replace(/^(\d{2,4})\d{2}$/, "$1:00")`

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
const maskHours = (value) => {
  return (
    value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/^(\d{2,4})\d+/, "$1:00")
  );
};
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2,4}                  digits (0-9) (between 2 and 4 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
```